# Using Ramda to handle promise and await

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ramda.js

I have a piece of code which was written using Lodash:

```js
    const profit =
      price -
      _.sumBy(
        await Promise.all(
          map(uOrder => uOrder.invoice, await order.upstreamOrders),
        ),
        'amount',
      );
```

I want to change it using Ramda, after thinking about it and reading some documentation, I wrote this:

```js
    const result = R.compose(
      R.pick(['amount']),
      await Promise.all(),
      R.map(await order.upstreamOrders, uOrder.invoice),
    );
```

of course it's wrong and not working, but its's my first approach and I want to know how to handle a situation like this using Ramda perfectly and in a functional way. How I can perform this?

Also order of object is array of following sample:

```
    { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59dce1f92d57920d3e62bdbc"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-10-10T15:06:34.111+0000"), 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-10-10T15:06:33.996+0000"), 
    "_customer" : ObjectId("59dce1f92d57920d3e62bd44"), 
    "_distributor" : ObjectId("59dce1f92d57920d3e62bd39"), 
    "status" : "NEW", 
    "cart" : [
        {
            "count" : NumberInt(1), 
            "_item" : ObjectId("59dce1f92d57920d3e62bd57"), 
            "_id" : ObjectId("59dce1f92d57920d3e62bdc1")
        }, 
        {
            "count" : NumberInt(1), 
            "_item" : ObjectId("59dce1f92d57920d3e62bd5c"), 
            "_id" : ObjectId("59dce1f92d57920d3e62bdc0")
        }, 
        {
            "count" : NumberInt(1), 
            "_item" : ObjectId("59dce1f92d57920d3e62bd61"), 
            "_id" : ObjectId("59dce1f92d57920d3e62bdbf")
        }, 
        {
            "count" : NumberInt(1), 
            "_item" : ObjectId("59dce1f92d57920d3e62bd66"), 
            "_id" : ObjectId("59dce1f92d57920d3e62bdbe")
        }, 
        {
            "count" : NumberInt(1), 
            "_item" : ObjectId("59dce1f92d57920d3e62bd6b"), 
            "_id" : ObjectId("59dce1f92d57920d3e62bdbd")
        }
    ], 
    "_upstreamOrders" : [
        "4545643499"
    ], 
    "key" : "4592846350", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(1), 
    "_invoice" : "0811260909610702"
}
```

Comment: `await` is keyword, not a function that can be composed. You need to desugar it into `then` and work with the promises explicitly. At best you can use [`composeP`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#composeP).

Comment: TBH, I don't see why you would want to use `compose` at all, there's nothing you need to change about the expression `await Promise.all(R.map(uOrder => uOrder.invoice, await order.upstreamOrders))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it'd be a good start to break down what exactly the original function is doing

```
const profit =
  price - // subtract the result
  _.sumBy(
    await Promise.all(
      // Wait for upstreamOrders to resolve, and grab the 'invoice'
      // key for each
      map(uOrder => uOrder.invoice, await order.upstreamOrders),
    ),
    // calculate the sum of the invoices, based on the 'amount' key
    'amount',
  );
```

With that in mind we can break down those steps, and separate the calculations (synchronous) from the data (async)

Ramda doesn't have a `sumBy`, as we can compose that from other functions. If you break it down, what we did was grab the `invoice` and the `amount` in two separate places, but we can just grab an array of amounts with

```
map(path(['invoice', 'amount']))
```

And we can drop that alongside a `sum` and `subtract` to create a function which is entirely independent from our async code

```
const calculateProfits = (price, orders) => compose(
  subtract(price),
  sum,
  map(path(['invoice', 'amount'])),
)(orders)
```

Allowing us to do something like:

```
const profit = calculateProfits(price, await order.upstreamOrders)
```

Or if `calculateProfits` was curried (and I'm not sure how upstreamOrders works, is it a getter that returns a promise?)

```
const getUpstreamOrders = order => order.upstreamOrders

getUpstreamOrders(order)
  .then(calculateProfits(price))
  .then(profits => {
    // Do what you want with the profits
  })
```

Finally, a few notes on the initial attempt

```
const result = R.compose(
  R.pick(['amount']),

  // Promise.all is being called without any arguments
  // it doesn't really fit within `compose` anyway, but if we were
  // feeding an array of promises through, we'd want to just
  // put `Promise.all,`
  await Promise.all(),

  // the arguments here should be the other way around, we're
  // mapping over upstreamOrders, and the data comes last
  // uOrder isn't available in this scope, previously it was
  // `uOrder => uOrder.invoice`,
  // invoking a function and returning the invoice for that order
  R.map(await order.upstreamOrders, uOrder.invoice),
);
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you. as your opinion how i should learn ramda perfectly? i coding with it abotut 1 month but still have trouble! \

Comment: Don't worry about learning it perfectly - there's no such thing! One thing that might help learning though is to split down the problems into their constituent parts. In this case it was separating the data fetching and the transformations, as well as testing each function in the `compose` individually and building it up. When I was answering I spun up the ramdajs.com/repl/ to get quick feedback and focus on the specific problem.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend getting familiar with the documentation, and these two wiki pages https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/What-Function-Should-I-Use%3F https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Cookbook. Even better if you can try and understand why the examples work!  The Thinking in ramda blog series is great too http://randycoulman.com/blog/2016/05/24/thinking-in-ramda-getting-started/

One of the most important things also is some of these functions are part of ramda, but on the whole the ideas are much bigger than ramda. Experiment with other fp libs, tutorials and even languages!